# isHighlighted and isSelected didSet only called for UICollectionViewCell not UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionviewcell

I want to apply some style changes to a custom table view cell on highlight/select so am overriding `isHighlighted` and `isSelected` to achieve this. It works for my custom collection view cells but not when I tap on the custom table view cells.

I set up the exact same scenario for a table view and collection view and implemented the following on the custom cells:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
   didSet {
     //called when I tap for CustomCollectionViewCell not for CustomTableViewCell
   }
}

override var isSelected: Bool {
  didSet {
     //called when I tap for CustomCollectionViewCell not for CustomTableViewCell
  }
}
```

What am I missing here? Why doesn't the table view cell did set get called when it's tapped? This happens for any table view I try with regardless of the content of the custom cell.

Comment: I’m asking why a custom table view cell doesn’t trigger the did set for isHighlighted and isSelected when tapped. No other details are needed imo

Comment: using `override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` instead.

Comment: @QuocNguyen this works thank you, can you tell me why overriding isHighlighted/isSelected doesn't work?

Comment: @jeh In the Apple's Doc wrote `isHighlighted/isSelected: A Boolean value that indicates whether the cell is selected.`. These variables like `get-only variable` so when you tap to cell, it's not call. But these variables are still called in initialization and when you direct call  `cell.isSelected=true`

Answer (score 27):

The other answer did not work for me. I reckon the reason is that `UITableViewCell.isSelected` setter is never called when the containing `UITableView` handles selection, that state is passed via `func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool)` instead. This means that overriding this function in your `UITableViewCell` subclass instead of the setter works:

```swift
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
  // implementation that was meant to be in `isSelected` `didSet`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By overriding these properties this way, you are no longer using their default implementations.

Try relaying information to `super`:

```
override var isHighlighted: Bool {
    get {
        return super.isHighlighted
    }
    set {
        //do something
        super.isHighlighted = newValue
    }

override var isSelected: Bool {
    get {
        return super.isSelected
    }
    set {
        //do something
        super.isSelected = newValue
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I want to change the background of the button in other words the background of the cell in the collection view:

```
class CustomCVCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            grayBackgroundViewWithImage.image =
                isSelected ? UIImage(named: "") : UIImage()
        }
    }
```

In the main class where the collection view is stored create this variable:

```
class CustomViewController: UIViewController {

///save the indexPath of last selected cell
private var lastSelectedIndexPath: IndexPath? }
```

In viewDidLoad() set this value to false:

```
customCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = false
```

Further code in data source. In my case, the first cell should be is selected:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CustomCVCell.cellID(),
                                                  for: indexPath) as! CustomCVCell
    
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
        cell.isSelected = true
    }
    
    //update last select state from lastSelectedIndexPath
    cell.isSelected = (lastSelectedIndexPath == indexPath)
    
    return cell
}
```

Further code in the delegate:

```
///UICollectionViewDelegate
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard lastSelectedIndexPath != indexPath else { return }

         if let index = lastSelectedIndexPath {
            let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: index) as! CustomCVCell
            cell.isSelected = false
          }

          let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CustomCVCell
          cell.isSelected = true
    lastSelectedIndexPath = indexPath
}
```

Comment: The question is why the same strategy doesn't work on UITableViewCell